# Arabic characters don't show in excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, locale, arabic, unicode-string

I can't write arabic strings in VBA code in excel, it shows as weird characters. Tried it on many machines with excel 2013 or 2010, on windows 8 or windows 7, with or without arabic proofing tools installed. Arabic language is already installed on all machines, system locale is arabic. There's no problem typing arabic characters on excel worksheets or even MS word but not in VBA code.

Comment: The workaround for me was to import modules from other software like Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 15):

in VB Editor:

- 1- click Tools
- 2- select Options...
- 3- click Editor Format
- 4- change font to `Courier New (Arabic)`
- 5- click OK

now you can write in both English and Arabic
I hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

**In Windows XP:**

1. > Control Panel
2. > Regional and Language Options
3. > Advanced Tab
4. > Select Arabic (depending on your country) You will be asked to insert the Windows CD, insert it and then browse to the I386 Folder then press ok.
5. > restart the PC and it should work now fine.

I beleve it's the same on Windows 7, the whole problem is in the non-unicode programs section set it to Arabic.

Answer (score 1):

In win 10, you must change your system locale to match your language. You can find it here:
1- Press win key or click on it
2- Type region and click on it when windows finds it
3- Choose administrative tab
4- Under the language for non-unicode programs you will find "change system locale" key
5- A restart would be required