# Change specific word to Arabic characters, including the character "ー"

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change "grape" to グレープ and below is the code I wrote,
but If I insert "ー" it is displayed as "?".

How can I solve this problem...??

```
Sub change_name()

    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Selection
            c.Value = Replace(c.Value, "grape", "グレ?プ")       
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948424/using-multiple-language-english-chinese-japanese-in-vba) helps.

Comment: Check my response in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53509921/vba-macro-to-search-a-text-string-and-replace-with-hyperlink-works-only-with-eng/53526940#53526940. Notice how it uses the `ChrW` unicode values for non-Latin characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing グレープ in a Named Range. Formulas > Name Manager > New >

"ReplaceText", Refers To:
="グレープ"

Then adjust your For Loop with:

```
c.Value = Replace(c.Value, "grape", Evaluate(Names("ReplaceText").Value))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. Actually whole code I wrote is 

Sub change()
    Dim c As Range
        
    word1 = InputBox(Prompt:="Before", Title:="change")
    word2 = InputBox(Prompt:="After", Title:="change")
    

    
        For Each c In Selection
                c.Value = Replace(c.Value, word1, word2)

        Next
End Sub

Unfortunately the word I want to change to is random. I there any good way for this ?

Comment: @tehoo you’d have to just keep adding names for each replacement you’d like to do