# vlookup error in vba userform with string value in Arabic

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, vlookup, userform

I have a problem using the lookup function in userforms in vba

what I want is return value from a table using vlookup
as the value of lookup is string and the end result is integer

I am using this and now working but it is working with another table which contain only numerics; but not working with a table contain texts (Arabic text ) .

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
Dim x As String


x = Me.ComboBox3.Value
Me.TextBox5.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x,
                    Worksheets("masterfile").Range("pricerange"), 2, False)     

End Sub
```

kindly help me

Comment: This [answer might be of some value to you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18868029/1389394). Could you let us know if you do a test vlookup for English text in your combobox if your function works.

Comment: sorry for that i dont know what happened but its working now with the below code 
as i deleted all text boxes and made from start . 

Private Sub item1_Change()


Dim x As String


x = Me.item1.Value


Me.TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, Worksheets("masterfile").Range("pricerange"), 2, False)



End Sub

Comment: Then you can post that as an answer. Make sure you indicate in your answer that it's working for Arabic text and that you have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for that i dont know what happened but its working now with the below code as i deleted all text boxes and made from start .

```
 Private Sub item1_Change() Dim x As String x = Me.item1.Value Me.TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, Worksheets("masterfile").Range("pricerange"), 2, False) End Sub
```